# How to change colors of the tracking points and connector lines on the output using Mediapipe Pose for Android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, mediapipe

I am referring to 33 body points and connector lines between them. I'd like to change the colors of those, especially of the white default color of the connector lines.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        previewDisplayView = new SurfaceView(this);
        setupPreviewDisplayView();

        AndroidAssetUtil.initializeNativeAssetManager(this);
        eglManager = new EglManager(null);
        processor = new FrameProcessor(
                        this,
                        eglManager.getNativeContext(),
                        BINARY_GRAPH_NAME,
                        INPUT_VIDEO_STREAM_NAME,
                        OUTPUT_VIDEO_STREAM_NAME);
        
        processor.getVideoSurfaceOutput().setFlipY(FLIP_FRAMES_VERTICALLY);

        processor.addPacketCallback(
                OUTPUT_LANDMARKS_STREAM_NAME,
                (packet) -> {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Received Pose landmarks packet.");
                    byte[] landmarksRaw = PacketGetter.getProtoBytes(packet);
                    NormalizedLandmarkList poseLandmarks = NormalizedLandmarkList.parseFrom(landmarksRaw);
                }
        );
        PermissionHelper.checkAndRequestCameraPermissions(this);
}
```